# Accessing an image folder inside public web directory

Tags: php, images, directory, linux

I have put a folder in the public web directory of my WordPress installation where I have some images used by a legacy system.

Say its located under `http://example.com/legacy-images/image1.png`.

I have changed the rights on that folder to `0444` so it should be readable.

For some reason, I can't access the images in that folder. For some reason it returns `404`.

Any clues on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

For directory (folder), only `read` is not enough. You need to set `execute` also. Because for directory, `execute` means you can enter the directory.

## Files need `read` permission & directory needs `read` & `execute` permission.

So the directory permission should be: `0555`. However, image files inside that directory should be just `read`, in numeric form: `0444`.

For example, in your case, `/legacy-images/` directory will have `0555` permission & `/legacy-images/image1.png` image file will have `0444` permission.

## Shell Command

If you can access shell and know how to, you may use the following shell commands (replace `<WP_DIRECTORY>` with appropriate WordPress installation directory):

```
cd <WP_DIRECTORY>
chmod 555 legacy-images/
cd legacy-images/
find ./ -type f -exec chmod 444 {} \;
```